# Factoring a polynomium with no pattern

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Along the way of deriving the formula for a sum of integer squares on [this webpage](https://web.archive.org/web/20171230141457/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55041.html) (it is about proving the pyramid volume formula), I noticed this step:

$$2n^2+7n+6=(n+2)(2n+3)$$

From right-to-left, you simply multiply the terms into each other's brackets.

But from **left-to-right**, as is done in the proof, I can't figure out the method.

Is there are formula for such factoring or is it simply a "good guess"?

Comment: [Rational roots theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) says $n=-2,-\frac32$ are roots.  Use this to find factors.

Comment: The *Rational roots theorem* may be used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $2n^2+7n+6$ is a simple quadratic with discriminant $\Delta = 49-48=1$ and roots $\cfrac{-7 \pm \sqrt{1}}{4}=-2,-\frac{3}{2}\,$, therefore it is divisible by $(n+2)(n+\frac{3}{2})$. The dominant coefficient is $2\,$, so the full factorization is $\,2(n+2)(n+\frac{3}{2}) = (n+2)(2n+3)\,$.

Comment: What does it mean that the dominant coefficient is 2?

Comment: @Steeven The coefficient of $n^2$ in the given polynomial is $2$, so it must be $2$ in its factorization, which was determined to be of the form $a(n+2)(n+\frac{3}{2})\,$, therefore $a=2$.

Answer (score 0):

The trick as always when dealing with polynomials with integer coefficients is to use the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

In your case, if $p/q$ is a root of $2X^2+7X+6$, then $q\vert 2$ and $p\vert 6$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the box method. What two numbers do you multiply to get $12$ and add to get $7$?

We have the tuple (3, 4). Draw a square box on your paper and divide it into four quadrants. Fit $2x^2$ on the top-left, and $6$ on the lower-right. Then fit $3x$ on the top-right box and $4x$ in the lower-left box.

Find the greatest common factors. In the first row, $x$ is the common factor. In the second row, $2$ is the common factor.

In the first column, $2x$ is the common factor. In the second column, $3$ is the common factor.

Therefore, you get $(x+2)(2x+3)$. [You may be able to find more helpful examples here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/factquad2.htm) demonstrating the use of this method.